# Bootstrap alignment of labels

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to create a form where I have a mix of 1 control, 2 control and 3 controls and the label at the top for a group. Following is my HTML. Can anybody help me to align the following form?

```
<div class=" col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3">
                            <div class="row">
                               <label>Label1</label><span class="mandatory">*</span>
                               <div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-12 form-group">                                        
                                        <select class="form-control input-sm"></select>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-5 col-xs-12 form-group">                                        
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm"
                                            required />
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-5 col-xs-12 form-group">                                            
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" required />
                                    </div>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <label>Label2</label><span class="mandatory">*</span>
                                <div>
                                <div class="col-xs-12 form-group">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" required />
                                </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12 form-group">
                                    <label>Label3</label><span class="mandatory">*</span>
                                <div class="input-group date">
                                    <label class="input-group-addon">##</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" />
                                </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12 form-group">
                                    <label>Label4</label><span class="mandatory">*</span>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" />
                                </div>

                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <label>Label5</label><span class="mandatory">*</span>
                                <div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-12 form-group">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" required />
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-5 col-xs-12 form-group">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" required />
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-5 col-xs-12 form-group">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" required />
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12 form-group">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" required />
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12 form-group">
                                        <select class="form-control input-sm"></select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <label>Label6</label><span class="mandatory">*</span>
                                <div>
                                <div class="col-xs-12 form-group">
                                    <input type="email" class="form-control input-sm" required />
                                </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12 form-group">
                                    <label>Label7</label><span class="mandatory">*</span>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" required />
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12 form-group">
                                    <label>Label8</label>
                                    <input type="text"  class="form-control" required />
                                </div>

                            </div>     </div>
```

Fiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/nxLz2up3/

Comment: 3 things, 1. We need far more info about current output vs desired output. It is not clear at all what you desire layout to look like. 2. Please indent and clean example code up always. 3. There are HUNDREDS of example bootstrap form layouts out there, just google "bootstrap form example", "bootstrap form template", ect. Some will be part of custom bootstrap themes, but those themes mostly just affect minor look and feel, the grid layout examples they give can still be of use at times, and there are many dedicated lists and sites about various form layouts

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<div class=" col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <label>Label1</label>
          <span class="mandatory">*</span>
        </div>
        <div>
          <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-12 form-group">
            <select class="form-control input-sm"></select>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-5 col-xs-12 form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" required="">
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-5 col-xs-12 form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" required="">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <label>Label2</label>
          <span class="mandatory">*</span>
        </div>
        <div>
          <div class="col-xs-12 form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" required="">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12 form-group">
          <label>Label3</label>
          <span class="mandatory">*</span>
          <div class="input-group date">
            <label class="input-group-addon">##</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12 form-group">
          <label>Label4</label>
          <span class="mandatory">*</span>
          <input type="text" class="form-control">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <label>Label5</label>
          <span class="mandatory">*</span>
        </div>
        <div>
          <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-12 form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" required="">
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-5 col-xs-12 form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" required="">
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-5 col-xs-12 form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" required="">
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12 form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" required="">
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12 form-group">
            <select class="form-control input-sm"></select>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <label>Label6</label>
          <span class="mandatory">*</span>
        </div>
        <div>
          <div class="col-xs-12 form-group">
            <input type="email" class="form-control input-sm" required="">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12 form-group">
          <label>Label7</label>
          <span class="mandatory">*</span>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" required="">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12 form-group">
          <label>Label8</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" required="">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```